# Using the IFERROR Function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I recently tried to change the VBA code

```
 Range("J2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=INDEX(Accounts!R2C3:R491C3,MATCH(RC[-8],Accounts!R2C2:R491C2,0))"
```

to

```
 Range("J2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=IFERROR(INDEX(Accounts!R2C3:R491C3,MATCH(RC[-8],Accounts!R2C2:R491C2,0)),"")"
```

but received an error on the latter code.  Is there something simple I am missing?

UPDATE:  The same error occurs with the following code:

```
Range("J2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR((=INDEX(Accounts!R2C3:R" & lastrow & "C3,MATCH(RC[-8],Accounts!R2C2:R" & lastrow & "C2,0)),"""")"
```

In the above,  `lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: what in `lastrow`: `Accounts!R2C2:R" & lastrow & "C2,0`?

Comment: change `"=IFERROR((=INDEX(Accounts!` to `"=IFERROR(INDEX(Accounts!`

Comment: @simoco Edited.  I should note that I have changed every formula so that it has R2C3:R" & lastrow & "C3 and those without IFERROR still work.  I should have edited that in the question.

Comment: @simoco That worked perfectly, I apologize for being a bit dense there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use double quotes in formula:

```
Range("J2:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IFERROR(INDEX(Accounts!R2C3:R491C3,MATCH(RC[-8],Accounts!R2C2:R491C2,0)),"""")"
```

Comment: After trying that out it did not seem to resolve the issue.  Is there nothing else that needs to be changed?  If it helps, it's an "application defined, object defined" error.